# jQuery Radio Button set doesnt work with older version of library

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have loaded the jquery version 1.6 and jquery ui version 1.8 and radio buttonset for UI doesn't seem to be working?

```
  $('#rx-button').buttonset();
  $("#rx-button> input:radio").button({disabled:true});
```

[Link to JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8ygnv/22/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery's UI library -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/rwwkH/)

Comment: Thank you @Andy Holmes, But still the radio button set is not working!

Comment: Sorted it, looks like you had linked the css wrong somehow. Updated my fiddle :)

Comment: Yeah, It works with newer version of UI and JQUERY but when I try with older version of Jquery(1.6.4) and UI(1.8.16) its not working? Any reason? why?

Comment: Can't see anything obvious, only thing is that even though you are calling the older version of UI in, it isn't listed on their site as a download, i'd take that as a hint to upgrade! haha. But honestly can't work that one out, bit odd